# How to scale ggplot stacked bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a set of data here

```
structure(list(Variants = c(35, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 97, 
6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 133, 6, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 51499, 
3508, 486, 155, 21, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0), Impact = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("HIGH", "LOW", "MODERATE", 
"MODIFIER"), class = "factor"), Number.of.dogs = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-40L))
```

I am trying to make a stacked bar graph using ggplot2.

```
ggplot(all, aes(fill=Impact, y=Variants, x=Number.of.dogs, label = Variants)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

The issue is, the first bar is so large that is messing up the scale so you can't see any of the values. Here is a picture of the graph. I was wondering if there was a way to change the scale of the y axis so that you can see the values associated with each section of the bar graph?  [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

`scale_y_continuous(trans='log2')`

or as @Rui pointed out in the comments, since the data contains 0's the following function would be more suitable

`trans=pseudo_log_trans(base = 2)`

Comment: The data has zeros. `scale_y_continuous(trans='pseudo_log')` is better?

Comment: Or `trans=pseudo_log_trans(base = 2)` for base 2.

Comment: @Brian it does, that;s the drawback for transforming the scale, the other issue is that you wan to visualize both the magnitude (the y ) and the categorical variable (the fill) it's impossible  to log transform and reconcile those two.